# libcurl.lib - where can I get it

Tags: libcurl

libcurl is what I am going to try to use for posting messages to a JMS queue from a C program running on Windows XP compiled using Visual Studio 6.

With this I need to link in libcurl.lib - but where do i get this from?

I link numerous lib's to my program (wsock32.lib, kernel32.lib, etc) so once I can get hold of it I can't see a problem.

I have downloaded all of the Win32-Generic binaries etc (http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) but none of them contain the lib/headers I need.

Anyone out there know where I get get them from.

thanks for any help.

- Problems running on a 64bit machine now - please see my 'answer' post

Comment: Have you downloaded packages marked as devel?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the link you supplied ([direct link](http://curl.haxx.se/download/libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip)). I now link in the libcurl_imp.lib to my dll and it compiles fine.  My app can call my new library routines that call the curl methods fine and works a treat - **BUT ONLY ON A 64BIT MACHINE?** - if I try to run the same dll/binary app on a 32bit XP machine it just dumps out immediately. In fact all my applications abort - and they make no reference to my new library routines, they just use the dll.  It seems that just because I build in the cURL calls into my dll it immediately aborts the spawned process– I just get –

> [1](http://curl.haxx.se/download/libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip) + Done(134) testapp
>
> 5656  Abort   testapp

I have a printf statement immediately after main but I get no output on the command line.

I then removed all my new library functions from the dll apart from one, and in this all I do is –

`CURLcode res = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);`

This one line causes all my apps to fail on 32bit when built into my dll – comment it out and they all work.

As stated, the same dll/binary works fine on my 64bit machine.  The 64bit machine has the same curllib.dll as the one on my 32bit machine.

For info, my build machine is 32bit, we have productions machines that are both 32 and 64 bit.

Is the link you sent me actually 64bit only?

Comment: I have started another thread for this question. Please ignore this post and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493300/libcurl-dll-error-on-32bit-but-not-64bit