# libcurl - dll error on 32bit but not 64bit

Tags: curl, libcurl

This is a new thread started from post ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107885/libcurl-lib-where-can-i-get-it)).

I have used the suggested curl library ([link](http://curl.haxx.se/download/libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip)) for building libcurl into my dll. I link in libcurl_imp.lib and have created library routines for calling the curl methods.  This all  works a treat - BUT ONLY ON A 64BIT MACHINE? - if I try to run the same dll/binary app on a 32bit XP machine it just dumps out immediately. In fact all my applications abort - and they make no reference to my new library routines, they just use the dll. It seems that because I build in the cURL calls into my dll it immediately aborts the spawned process– I just get –

> 1 + Done(134) testapp
>
> 5656 Abort testapp

I have a printf statement immediately after main but I get no output on the command line.

I then removed all my new library functions from the dll apart from one, and in this all I do is –

`CURLcode res = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);`

This one line causes all my apps to fail on 32bit when built into my dll – comment it out and they all work.

As stated, the same dll/binary works fine on my 64bit machine. The 64bit machine has the same curllib.dll runtime as the one on my 32bit machine.

For info, my build machine is 32bit, we have productions machines that are both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Further to this - the curl.exe contained in the .zip produces the same result (aborts immediately) when ran from the command line on my 32bit XP machine - works fine from 64bit...?

Comment: Another thing... the curl.exe contained in the downloads under Win32-Generic (the 2000/XP ones) DO run on my XP machine. Only problem is is that there are no .lib's contained in these downloads!!! Does anyone out there know how to request a new libcurl windows build to be done as dare I say it, it would seem that 7.19.3 under Win32-MSVC does not work on 32bit OS.